# How to use logitech lua scripting

Tags: lua, scripting, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to have two inputs that will lead to one output. This is so I can use an ability in a game thanks if you can help.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg) 
     if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 then --set flag for mb2
            mb2_pressed = true
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 2 then --set flag for mb2=false
        mb2_pressed = false
    else if event == "LSHIFT_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
    leftshift_pressed = true
    else if event == "LSHIFT_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
    leftshift_pressed = false
    end
end

if leftshift_pressed and  if mb2_pressed then
presskey("9")
        Sleep(50)
        releasekey("9")
end
end
```

https://gyazo.com/7e7f2139fabb22d1e06f8f3f169cb4bb

Comment: And where do you have a problem?

Comment: theres a syntax error im getting https://gyazo.com/3e9daf401e4a4baaf219f01f96fd0a7c

Answer (score 1):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 and IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
      PressAndReleaseKey("lshift")
      PressAndReleaseKey("9")
   end
end
```

You should know the following:

- LGS/GHUB has a bug in line numbering, "line 12" in error message actually means line#13 in your code (and red stripe is also set at wrong position)
- `if leftshift_pressed and  if mb2_pressed then` is a syntax error, you should write `if leftshift_pressed and mb2_pressed then`
- `if`/`elseif`/`else`/`end` must be balanced.  Yours are not.  Use indentation in the code to make it obvious.
- There is no event `LSHIFT_BUTTON_PRESSED`, you receives events only from G-buttons (all buttons on Logitech mouse and special G-buttons on Logitech keyboard).
- Uppercase is different from lowercase: `PressKey` is not the same as `presskey`

Comment: thanks its kind of working but instead of ouputting 9 its displaying a "("

Comment: Yes, while shift is down, key `9` is treated as `(`

Comment: thx for helping however that one doesnt work well what was the old code before?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work well?  You can see previous versions of the answer by clicking at "edited XX mins ago" link

Comment: in this version after I use the macro shift is staying pressed / staying on even even after the key presses. Its just weird.

Comment: ok its working correctly to display 9 however the game isnt registering it as pressing 9 for the skill so I rebound the key in game and also I changed the code to only press mouse 2 and output N and its working in game.